powers of primitive element form basis of simple extension
Let $E/F$ be a finite extension of fields, $r \in E$ an element whose minimal polynomial is $f \in F[x]$, and $n = [F(r) : F]$.
How can I show that $S = \{1, r, \dots, r^{n-1}\}$ is a basis of $F(r)$ over $F$?
The goal is to show every ratio of polynomials in $r$ is in $\text{Span}(S)$.
Looking at $f$ shows that $r^n \in \text{Span}(S)$, and looking at $r^{-1}f$ shows that $r^{-1} \in \text{Span}(S)$. By induction now every power $r^i \in \text{Span}(S)$. Now I am stuck.
